# Getting error when i am using @trasactional with service methodand Also I Have problem to use @EnableTransactionManagement

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, repository

Field passengerInfoRepository in paymentgateway.service.FlightBookingService required a bean of type 'paymentgateway.repository.PassengerInfoRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'paymentgateway.repository.PassengerInfoRepository' in your configuration.

Controller Class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@RestController
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"paymentgateway.repository, paymentgateway.service"})
public class PaymentgatewayApplication {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PaymentgatewayApplication.class);

    @Autowired//declared whether dependency 
    private FlightBookingService flightBookingService;
    
    @PostMapping("/bookFlightTicket")
    public FlightBookingAcknowledgement bookFlightTicket(@RequestBody FlightBookingRequest flightBookingRequest) {
        logger.trace("Flightbooking in service: {} ", flightBookingService.bookFlightTicket(flightBookingRequest));
        return flightBookingService.bookFlightTicket(flightBookingRequest);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PaymentgatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class FlightBookingService {
    
    @Autowired
    private PassengerInfoRepository passengerInfoRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private PaymentInfoRepository paymentInfoRepository;
    
    @Transactional//(readOnly = false , isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public FlightBookingAcknowledgement bookFlightTicket(FlightBookingRequest flightBookingRequest) {
        
        
        PassengerInfo passengerInfo =  flightBookingRequest.getPassengerInfo();
        
         passengerInfo = passengerInfoRepository.save(passengerInfo);
        
        PaymentInfo paymentInfo = flightBookingRequest.getPaymentInfo();
        
        PaymentUtils.validateCreditLimit(paymentInfo.getAccountNo(), passengerInfo.getFare());
        
        paymentInfo.setAmount(passengerInfo.getFare());
        paymentInfo.setPassengerId(passengerInfo.getPId());
        paymentInfoRepository.save(paymentInfo);
        
        return new FlightBookingAcknowledgement("success", passengerInfo.getFare(),UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")[0],passengerInfo);
        
    }

}
```

Two Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PassengerInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<PassengerInfo, Long> {

}


@Repository
public interface PaymentInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<PaymentInfo, String>{

}
```

appliction.properties.

```
server.port = 8081
```

configuartio.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/GT
spring.datasource.username=said
spring.datasource.password=said  
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "PASSENGER_INFO")
public class PassengerInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Long pId;
    private String name; 
    private String email;
    private String source;
    private String destination;
    
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date travelDate;
    private String pickupTime;
    private String arrivalTime;
    private double fare;
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAYMENT_INFO")
public class PaymentInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2" , strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String paymentId;
    private String accountNo;
    private double amount ;
    private String cardType;
    private Long passengerId;
}
```

Comment: please Like it and give me answer for this.if i made mistake please correct it

Comment: You want a datasource but disabled the auto configuration. Remove the exclude from `@SpringBootApplication`. Place your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in the `paymentgateway` package and remove the `@ComponentScan`. The `@Repository` is useless on Spring Data repository interfaces and you don't need `@EnableTransactionManagement` as that is automatic. Finally don't use `@Data` fo entities as that generates a wrong toString/equals/hashCode for JPA (and lead to some surprising side effects).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, but the main problem being excluding the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` in your setup. Remove that exclude as you need a datasource. No `DataSource` no JPA, no Spring Data JPA repositories.

Another thing is to remove the `@ComponentScan` and place your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in the top-level `paymentgateway` package. That way it will automatically discover the repositories, services etc. etc. instead of you having to add more and more annotations to make it work.

Spring Boot automatically enables transactions so you don't need `@EnableTransactionManagement`. Yours is disabled due to the first issue as there is nothing that needs to be transactions (no datasource, no JPA etc.)

Spring Data repositories don't need an `@Repository` annotation as they are discovered through different means. So they only add clutter/overhead to your code, so remove them.

Don't use `@Data` for your `@Entities` it generates wrong `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode` methods for JPA. Not to mention that it can lead to surprising side effects like an 1+N select problem due to this. See https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/ for more info. The short answer is define your own `equals`/`hashcode` and use `@Getter`/`@Setter`.